# Using same EJB in multiple Applications running in same weblogic cluster

Tags: ejb, weblogic

I have a core component that is used by 3 different applications. All of the 3 applications are deployed within the same web logic cluster. The core component consist of few stateless EJBs that's are used by all of the 3 application. As of now I have my applications bundled and deployed as follows

**Application 1:**

app1.ear

app1.xml

core.ear (this includes the ejbs that are used by all 3 applications)

**Application 2:**

app2.ear

app2.xml

core.ear

**Application 3:**

app3.ear

app3.xml

core.ear

My question is do I need to deploy the core component with all the 3 applications (the way I am doing now)? Or just deploy it with one of the applications and other 2 applications will be able to use that component since all of them are deployed in the same cluster?

Comment: I am using web logic 12c

Answer (score 0):

Uhm...no you don't need to deploy the core in all the three ear. But the point is that you will have to do a JNDI lookup to access the EJB from other ear.

If your bean has been successfully deployed, you have two options for retrieving the JNDI name:

1. Look in weblogic JNDI tree and get the reference of your EJB
2. Look in the startup log, the container should tell you the JNDI name

Or, if you look at the documentation [Accessing Enterprise Bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html), you will notice that since JEE6 the JNDI naming convention for EJB has become a standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Leonardo. It helps a lot.

Comment: Just for curiosity, in future if the applications are scattered in different cluster, will this approach work?